# How Should an OS X Drawing Programs Store Custom Data in its PDF PasteBoard Flavor?

Tags: macos, pdf-generation, copy-paste, interop

A little history. In the days when the pre-eminent Mac vectored clipboard flavor was PICT, a program could insert its own data into the PICT. The PICT could be pasted into another application. At some later date, the same drawing could be selected and put on the clipboard, and pasted back into the originating program. The originating program would extract its custom data and regenerate the original selection for live editing.

These days, the dominant vectored clipboard flavor is PDF, which is a fine format, but Apple does not provide any means to put one's custom data into a PDF using Apple's PDF generating APIs. (If I'm wrong about this, please let me know.) Just standard strings like the title, author, etc. And it seems that new applications often do not bother to put the original graphic back on the clipboard if the selection consists solely of the original. Also, applications like Word only keep the first page of pasted PDFs.

Is there any thing I can do today to get "round trip" editing from my app to an arbitrary other app? Baring this, what would be the ideal solution for Apple and other apps to support? Should it be like PICT and be a standard custom vendor blob embedded in PDF, or should there be a separate vendor pasteboard type that apps keep in parallel with the visible graphic? If the former, should the blob be kept at the document or page level? I would prefer not to try anything hacky, like jamming XML into the author field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though there is a new API that will become available in 10.7 (and is already available in iOS) that allows the inclusion of arbitrary (XML based) metadata.

```
void CGPDFContextAddDocumentMetadata (CGContextRef context, CFDataRef metadata) CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_0);
```

This will insert a compressed Metadata stream referenced from the Root dictionary. All I've got to go on here is the API call that magically appeared in the CGPDFContext.h header file. Obviously, this doesn't help me support OS X versions prior to 10.7, but it seems like the long term solution, and in the meantime we can hack the PDF to match this.

[Here's a blog entry I wrote up on the subject.](http://sprinkleofcocoa.blogspot.com/2010/09/finally-apple-embraces-standard-for.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another hack would be to use the PDFKit to add annotations with your extra data in them -- I'm not sure if those would be copied/pasted correctly by target programs, but it's worth a try.

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFAnnotation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Example Code](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/PDFAnnotationEditor/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004035)

-W

Comment: Hi Wil. Thanks for the reply. Hope Delicious Library is still selling well. Regardless, I'm really not wanting a hack, but it's looking more and more like I'll need one. It doesn't look as there will be an Apple sanctioned method any time soon. I'm wondering if it would be somewhat less hacky long term to munge a PDF I get from the Apple APIs to insert my own resource. For instance, I could append a comment to the PDF file "% com.mycompany.MyData=blahblahblah"
where blahblahblah would be a properly escaped XML snippet, or I could add it in a more PDFish way consistent with the format.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why whatever it is your application needs to draw cannot be expressed in PDF format and hidden? While there are plenty of complaints about PDF's irksome limitations in the pre-press industry, Apple has nothing to do with them, and the fact of the matter is that it's really pretty good at making pretty pictures appear on both screens and pieces of paper.

Which API are you looking at?

Comment: I'm using the standard API for generating PDF content under OS X, such as CGPDFContextCreate. 

My feeling is that just as there is an API now for adding keyword support using the kCGPDFContextKeywords tag, then there should be a means for me to supply an arbitrarily large chunk of XML to allow me to recreate the original selection. I do not want to use any hacks like adding transparent text with my XML.

Comment: If that's a hack then some of Adobe's best selling flagship products are in trouble. Create an Illustrator document with non-printing objects in it and see what that looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You need a higher level API. The low-level CGPDF... API probably will be less useful to you than directly using Cocoa. (If you're not using Cocoa, God help you.) You can do everything you need to do by using the standard PDF support in Cocoa, plus selected drop-downs into CoreGraphics directly for efficiency. (Cocoa is great, but sucks at highly efficient graphics drawing.)

Comment: Could you give me an example?